# csv export showing HTML tags in the CSV file and only shows one record

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, export-to-csv, razorengine

I would be very grateful if you could help me out with the following code.. I can read a local .xls file and show it on the browser using jQuery jTable, I can also export the data to .csv file but for some reason it is showing HTML tags in the downloaded file, which I believe is due to using

```
HtmlTextWriter tw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
gridvw.RenderControl(tw);
```

Also, it only shows one record when downloaded the .CSV file.. I tried using `TextWriter` but doesn't show anything.

```
public ActionResult ExportToCsv()
{
    string Path = @"C:\\5Newwithdate.xls";
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= '" + Path + "';Extended Properties=" + (char)34 + "Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;" + (char)34 + "");
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", con);
    con.Close();
    System.Data.DataTable data = new System.Data.DataTable();
    da.Fill(data);
    SQLDBBillingProvider sql = new SQLDBBillingProvider();
    List<TopPlayed> daa = new List<TopPlayed>();

    foreach (DataRow p in data.Rows)
    {
        TopPlayed top = new TopPlayed()
        {
            TrackID = p.Field<double>("ID").ToString(),
            TrackName = p.Field<string>("Track Name"),
            ArtistName = p.Field<string>("Artist Name"),
            Times = p.Field<double>("NoOfPlays").ToString()
        };

        System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView gridvw = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();
        gridvw.DataSource = top.ArtistName.ToList().Take(7); 
        gridvw.DataBind();
        HttpContext.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=TopTracks.csv");
        HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Expires", "0");
        var sw = new StreamWriter(new MemoryStream());
        // Write the data here..
        HtmlTextWriter tw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        gridvw.RenderControl(tw);
        // Flush the stream and reset the file cursor to the start
        sw.Flush();
        sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        // return the stream with Mime type
        return new FileStreamResult(sw.BaseStream, "text/csv");
    }

    return View();
}
```

[image: download csv file]

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: What did you _expect_ it to do? It's a GridView - a control for rendering data as HTML. You rendered it to an HtmlTextWriter, which is an object used to render HTML. Your output is - HTML. Where did you do something to produce something _other_ than HTML?

Comment: Also, you return after the first row! That's why there's only one row!

Comment: yeah that's great and makes more sense now.. cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many issues , so little time:

You do not want to write out a grid at all. That was for your web view, but CSV can be generated directly from the data.

You want something like this:

```
public ActionResult ExportToCsv()
{
    string Path = @"C:\\5Newwithdate.xls";
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= '" + Path + "';Extended Properties=" + (char)34 + "Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;" + (char)34 + "");
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", con);
    con.Close();
    System.Data.DataTable data = new System.Data.DataTable();
    da.Fill(data);
    SQLDBBillingProvider sql = new SQLDBBillingProvider();
    List<TopPlayed> daa = new List<TopPlayed>();

    // Create a memory stream and a TextWriter that uses it for its output
    var sw = new StreamWriter(new MemoryStream());
    TextWriter tw = new TextWriter(sw);

    // Write the header row
    tw.WriteLine("\"ID\", \"Track\", \"Artist\", \"Plays\"");

    // Write the data here..
    foreach (DataRow p in data.Rows)
    {
        TopPlayed top = new TopPlayed()
        {
            TrackID = p.Field<double>("ID").ToString(),
            TrackName = p.Field<string>("Track Name"),
            ArtistName = p.Field<string>("Artist Name"),
            Times = p.Field<double>("NoOfPlays").ToString()
        };
        // Write a single CSV line
        tw.WriteLine(string.Format("\"{0}\", \"{1}\", \"{2}\", \"{3}\"", top.TrackID, top.TrackName, top.ArtistName, top.Times);
    }

    // Now return the stream to the client/browser    
    HttpContext.Response.ClearContent();
    HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=TopTracks.csv");
    HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Expires", "0");
    gridvw.RenderControl(tw);
    // Flush the stream and reset the file cursor to the start
    sw.Flush();
    sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    // return the stream with Mime type
    return new FileStreamResult(sw.BaseStream, "text/csv");

}
```

You do not actually need the TopPlayed object, but I did not want to change too much at once :)

That could become:

```
// Write the data here..
foreach (DataRow p in data.Rows)
{
    // Write a single CSV line direct from the database record
    tw.WriteLine(string.Format("\"{0}\", \"{1}\", \"{2}\", \"{3}\"", p.Field<double>("ID"), p.Field<string>("Track Name"), p.Field<string>("Artist Name"), p.Field<double>("NoOfPlays"));
}
```

Please note you do not need `(char)34` in your connection string. That represents a double-quote. Just escape any double-quote with 2 double quotes `""` (in an @-style string) or " (in a normal string).

e.g.

```
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + Path + @"';Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;""");
```

### Yet another version:

Also, you should always wrap objects that implement `IDisposable` in a `using` statement to ensure they are closed correctly/automatically when they go out of scope. If your `SQLDBBillingProvider` implements `IDisposable` it should also have a `using`.

I also noticed I do not need the extra `TextWriter` *isa* `StreamWriter` (i.e. it inherits `TextWriter` directly).

Please note I cannot compile this code as I do not have the missing parts, so there may be the odd typo:

```
public ActionResult ExportToCsv()
{
    string Path = @"C:\\5Newwithdate.xls";
    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= '" + Path + "';Extended Properties=" + (char)34 + "Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;" + (char)34 + ""))
    {
        using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", con))
        {
            con.Close();
            System.Data.DataTable data = new System.Data.DataTable();
            da.Fill(data);
            SQLDBBillingProvider sql = new SQLDBBillingProvider();
            List<TopPlayed> daa = new List<TopPlayed>();

            // Create a memory stream and a TextWriter that uses it for its output
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(new MemoryStream()))
            {
                // Write the header row
                sw.WriteLine("\"ID\", \"Track\", \"Artist\", \"Plays\"");

                // Write the data here..
                foreach (DataRow p in data.Rows)
                {
                    TopPlayed top = new TopPlayed()
                    {
                        TrackID = p.Field<double>("ID").ToString(),
                        TrackName = p.Field<string>("Track Name"),
                        ArtistName = p.Field<string>("Artist Name"),
                        Times = p.Field<double>("NoOfPlays").ToString()
                    };
                    // Write a single CSV line
                    sw.WriteLine(string.Format("\"{0}\", \"{1}\", \"{2}\", \"{3}\"", top.TrackID, top.TrackName, top.ArtistName, top.Times);
                }
                // Now return the stream to the client/browser    
                HttpContext.Response.ClearContent();
                HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=TopTracks.csv");
                HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Expires", "0");
                // Flush the stream and reset the file cursor to the start
                sw.Flush();
                sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                // return the stream with Mime type
                return new FileStreamResult(sw.BaseStream, "text/csv");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i can't thank you enough man.. it's working like a charm. thanks a lot :) for your help on this issue. Your answer is self explanatory and it's making soo many things clear. thanks again :) You're the man!

Comment: -1: please add `using` blocks as appropriate so that I can upvote.

Comment: where do you want me to add         using blocks? Sorry, im kinda new here so don't exactly know the basics of posting in here.. or do u want me to use using blocks in my code?

Comment: @John Saunders: Answer updated to cover using `using`. Feel free to modify it further yourself if I missed anything else :)

Comment: that's amazing man.. cheers again :) You're the Man! I'm using the updated version now.

Answer (score 0):

I had to tweak this bit of code as it was giving me errors sayin "Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface System.IO.TextWriter" so from

this

```
  var sw = new StreamWriter(new MemoryStream());
  TextWriter tw = new TextWriter(sw);
```

to this

```
    var tw = new StreamWriter(new MemoryStream());
 // TextWriter tw = new TextWriter(sw);
```

one small bit, in the CSV file the records are showing in between "" other than that it's great :)